# Communication between Android device(phone) and PC via USB coding

Tags: android, usb

I searched for some websites and learned that the way to communicate between android device(phone) and PC via USB is to have an app implementing serversocket on the phone and another app implementing client socket on PC. I kinda fixed the phone side's app(no exception now), but I got an exception "Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement" trying to initiate a socket("localhost", 38300). Does anybody know what's going on with this and how I can fix it? I attached both side's of the code below.

My step to get it to run is as follows

: environment:

Samsung Android phone, Linux PC, Android Studio developer run on Linux

: connection step

1. open android studio
2. install one app on phone
3. install another app on pc android emulator
4. launch phone side app and click on button to attempt to wait for connection
   at this step, adb devices will have two devices
5. adb -s emulator-5554 -s 1234567890(my phone) forward tcp:38300 tcp:38300
6. launch pc side android emulator app and click on the button to initiate client socket

NOTE: as you all can see that I can use android studio "Android Monitor" window to see both phone's and PC's app shell's log.

## phone side

```
    package com.example.seanhsu.androiddevice_serversocket;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class AndroidDevice_ServerSocket extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener{

    public static final String TAG = "Connection";
    public static final int TIMEOUT = 10;
    Intent i = null;
    TextView tv = null;
    private String connectionStatus = null;
    private String socketData = null;
    private Handler mHandler = null;
    ServerSocket server = null;

    String msg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_device__server_socket);

    // Set up click listeners for the buttons
    View connectButton = findViewById(R.id.connect_button);
    connectButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View onBtn = findViewById(R.id.hdmi_on);
    onBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    View offBtn = findViewById(R.id.hdmi_off);
    offBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    // i = new Intent(this, Connected.class);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.connect_button:
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connection_text);
            // initialize server socket in a new separate thread
            new Thread(initializeConnection).start();
            msg = "Attempting to connect...";
            Log.e(TAG, "1 "+msg);
            Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT/*msg.length()*/).show();
            break;
        case R.id.hdmi_on:
            Log.e(TAG, "disconnect" + Globals.socketOut);
            if (Globals.socketOut != null) {
                Globals.socketOut.println("hdmiOn");
                Globals.socketOut.flush();
                msg = "disconnect hdmi on";
                Log.e(TAG, "2 "+msg);
                Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT/*msg.length()*/).show();
            }
            else
            {
                msg = "disconnect hdmi on is null";
                Log.e(TAG, "3 "+msg);
                Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT/*msg.length()*/).show();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.hdmi_off:
            Log.e(TAG, "disconnect" + Globals.socketOut);
            if (Globals.socketOut != null) {
                Globals.socketOut.println("hdmiOff!!");
                Globals.socketOut.flush();
                msg = "disconnect hdmi off";
                Log.e(TAG, "4 "+msg);
                Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT/*msg.length()*/).show();
            }
            else
            {
                msg = "disconnect hdmi off is null";
                Log.e(TAG, "5 "+msg);
                Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT/*msg.length()*/).show();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    private Runnable initializeConnection = new Thread() {
    public void run() {

        Socket client = null;
        // initialize server socket
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(38300);
            server.setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT * 5000);

            // attempt to accept a connection
            client = server.accept();
            Globals.socketIn = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
            Globals.socketOut = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),
                    true);

            // Globals.socketIn.
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            // print out TIMEOUT
            Log.e(TAG, "aaa=== " + e);
            msg = "Connection has timed out! Please try again";
            Log.e(TAG, "6 "+msg);
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//method error, this causes program terminated
            mHandler.post(showConnectionStatus);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "bbb=== " + e);
            msg = "IO Exception";
            Log.e(TAG, "7 "+msg);
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//method error, this causes program terminated
        } finally {
            // close the server socket
            try {
                if (server != null)
                    server.close();
            } catch (IOException ec) {
                Log.e(TAG, "ccc=== " + ec);
                Log.e(TAG, "Cannot close server socket" + ec);
                msg = "Cannot close server socket";
                Log.e(TAG, "8 "+msg);
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//method error, this causes program terminated
            }
        }

        if (client != null) {
            Globals.connected = true;
            // print out success
            connectionStatus = "Connection was succesful!";
            Log.e(TAG, "9 "+connectionStatus);
            mHandler.post(showConnectionStatus);
            while (Globals.socketIn.hasNext()) {
                socketData = Globals.socketIn.next();
                mHandler.post(socketStatus);

            }
            // startActivity(i);
        }
    }
};
    /**
    * Pops up a "toast" to indicate the connection status
    */
    private Runnable showConnectionStatus = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Log.e(TAG, "10 "+connectionStatus);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), connectionStatus,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    };

    private Runnable socketStatus = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connection_text);
        tv.setText(socketData);
    }
    };

    public static class Globals {
    public static boolean connected;
    public static Scanner socketIn;
    public static PrintWriter socketOut;
    }
    }
```

## PC side

```
    package com.example.seanhsu.pchost_clientsocket_withactivity;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class PCHost_ClientSocket_with_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener{

    Socket socket;
    PrintWriter out;
    Scanner sc;
    String msg;

    private String TAG = "PCHost_ClientSocket_withActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pchost__client_socket_with_);
    View connectButton = findViewById(R.id.connect_button);
    connectButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    //when the emulator start running, it's already in the emulator shell, so it cann't execute adb command
    //execAdb();
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
    //cannot run on main thread
    //need to run on another thread, otherwise it will get android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException exception
    new Thread(initializeConnection).start();
    //initializeConnection();

    /*while(sc.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " / " + sc.nextLine());
        Log.e(TAG, "12 "+System.currentTimeMillis() + " / " + sc.nextLine());
    }*/
    }
    //cannot run on main thread
    //need to run on another thread, otherwise it will get android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException exception
    private Runnable initializeConnection = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        msg = "initializeConnection";
        Log.e(TAG, msg);

        //Create socket connection
        try{
            Log.e(TAG, "============0============");
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 38300);
            Log.e(TAG, "============1============");
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            Log.e(TAG, "============2============");
            //in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            sc=new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            Log.e(TAG, "============3============");
            // add a shutdown hook to close the socket if system crashes or exists unexpectedly
            Thread closeSocketOnShutdown = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Log.e(TAG, "============4============");
                        socket.close();
                        msg = "closeSocketOnShutdown socket close";
                        Log.e(TAG, msg);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "============5============");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        msg = "closeSocketOnShutdown IOException";
                        Log.e(TAG, msg);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            };
            Log.e(TAG, "============6============");
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(closeSocketOnShutdown);
            Log.e(TAG, "============7============");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            //Print.fatalError(“Socket connection problem (Unknown host)”+e.getStackTrace());
            msg = "Socket connection problem (Unknown host)"+e.getStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, msg);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Print.fatalError(“Could not initialize I/O on socket “+e.getStackTrace());
            msg = "Could not initialize I/O on socket "+e.getStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, msg);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};
}
```

I keep getting exception:

> Could not initialize I/O on socket [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@14710f5

Originally I also has IO exception on phone side app, but I add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in the manifest, it's OK now. Therefore, I also add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in PC side app's manifest, but still can't fix this problem.

Comment: Mainly the following errors:
1. [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement
2. FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-94
3. AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
.....

Comment: USB coding? Never heard of that. You are not even telling where your server runs. And where your client runs.

Comment: " trying to initiate a socket("localhost", 38300)." If it's only that line then why post all that code?

Comment: 'install one app on phone'. So what you should tell is if that is the server or the client. Adapt your post please.

Comment: 'Mainly the following errors: 1. [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement 2. FATAL EXCEPTION: '. Where? Client or server? On phone? Which code 'line?

Comment: hi all:
host: Linux PC
client: Android device(samsung phone)
<purpose>: need to establish communication between host and client
As I read from other websites, it says host(Linux PC) side should implement client socket,
and client(phone) side should implement server socket.

Comment: I also found the code from some websites and mofidy some codes to get them to run.
1. app on phone: using android studio on Linux PC and install phone side's app code onto the phone
2. app on Linux PC: using android studio and run the host side's app code on studio emulator

In short, I used android studio on Linux to write two apps, one for phone, one for Linux PC emulator.

Comment: Also heard from website, I follow the following steps:
1. adb forward tcp:38300 tcp:38300
2. launch phone's app, click on a button which will attemp to wait for connection
3. launch Linux's app in studio emulator

so far, by typing "adb devices", I will have two devices,
one if for emulator, eg: emulator-5554, and the other for phone, eg: 1234567890

**** I want these two apps to communicate and get USB data, but so far I have exception that
has something to do with socket.... error as I attached.

Comment: Final goal: I want to send data from PC to android device and store in it, so I need android device and pc to communicate via USB.

I think I am describing pretty clear what I am doing now here. Am I completely on the wrong track or?

Looking forward to your replying.

Comment: phone side's app is fine now, no exception, just timeout waiting for no connection
host side app runs on emulator when initialize connection(please see code),
it has exception: Could not initialize I/O on socket [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement...
also java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: Please do not talk about a 'phone side app'. Better talk about 'the client on my phone' or 'the server on my phone'. And realise that the one with the SeverSocket is the server. You are mixing it all up so i cannot follow you. Please put your explanations in your post and not in comments.

Comment: Dear greenapps:
The way I did it is following some website's sample code.
Someone did it and succeed. If you think I mixed up the whole
thing, the concept, the coding, anything, please explain to me
how I can communicate between an android device and PC host via
USB. I need to transfer data by USB. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here is the website that I followed:
http://qtcstation.com/2011/03/connecting-android-to-the-pc-over-usb/ , 
http://www.florescu.org/archives/2010/10/15/android-usb-connection-to-pc/
If you know how to do, please kindly let me know, the concept, how it works,
sample code is even better.

Comment: Sorry. I will not follow your links. I expect you to tell a consistent story and some code which gives troubles and some logcat output if needed.

Comment: Dear greenapps:
Let's forget about the whole thing now. In short,
I am trying to read write some data via USB between
android device and PC. Any idea? If you do know,
please give me a direction how I am gonna start. I don't
know why you won't follow the link's example code.
I am new to Android, and if you are willing to help me out,
that will be very helpful. I have searched many websites, but
can't really find a lot of info that I needed for me to even get
started.

Comment: Hi greenapps:
I finally got it to work now. However, I realized that what I did on both
android device side and PC side is just using adb to connect their sockets through tcp port. What I am trying to do further is that I need to read/write USB data. I read from some website saying that it needs AOAP protocol and run android device app in accessory mode in order to get it to work. I have had my accessory mode app ready on my android device, but I do not know what else
I need to do on PC side, and also I cannot find any website talking about AOAP. If you have any websites, pls
reply me. Thanks.

Comment: Hi greenapps:
Before going into AOAP, I run the accessory mode app on device,
it returns null accessories. Any idea why it's null?

Comment: Hi @seantobe I read all your comments. I am developing client-server communication through USB. Concept is like one server app and many clients. So how could achieve with your reference link. Should I do PC Side Code in server app and Client side code in client app? Through Can I achieve with this? I am confuse where should I do the code in which file. Thanks in advance.