# Android read data from laptop

Tags: android, server, client, wifi

I want to develop an android app that reads data (i.e text file) on a usb when I connect it to the laptop.
So the two main pillars here, how do I connect to the pc and how can I detect the flash drive to read from it.

Is it possible to do so without having to also write a server program for the desktop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34036056/communication-between-android-devicephone-and-pc-via-usb-coding

Comment: no it's not what i want, can you please tell me if you didn't get what i want

Comment: You can use samba to read shared folders of your pc. Smb protocol.